# Unable to write to GPIO pins using gpio command line utility

Tags: archlinux, rpi.gpio

I'm just done with installing ArchLinux ARM. I've also installed the `RPi.GPIO` and `WiringPi` packages. The problem is this:
Through the command line, using the `gpio` utility, I am able to change the modes of the pin and read successfully. But `write` makes no difference at all. `write` seems to be successful since `echo $?` returns 0. Did I miss any dependencies? As stated earlier, I have RPi.GPIO and WiringPi only. Thanks for helping!

EDIT: The "write" works with the pyhton implementation, `GPIO.output(...)`. Weird only command line tool's got the problem...

Comment: Why do you think write isn't working?  I'd say that over 50% of gpio problems are down to users not writing to the pin they think they are writing to.

Comment: Did you check permissions? Tried running gpio as root?

Comment: @joan: gpio readall shows no change either. The mode changes. But the value does not. Also, see the EDIT please. :)

Comment: @MarcoPoli Yes I've tried running it as root. No change :\

Comment: Which gpio numbering system are you using in RPi.GPIO (may be Broadcom or board) and which are you using in the gpio utility (defaults to wiringPi numbers, may use Broadcom numbers).

Comment: @joan :D yes, I've double checked, and am using Rev1 GPIO pin numbering system, with "-g" succeeding "gpio" command.

Comment: Which gpio/pin?

Comment: 17, 18 and 24 are the ones I've tried. Please note that I'm able to change the values through python RPi.GPIO package, which should be fine for me. But the fact that the command line does not work makes me a little uneasy.

Comment: There is nothing special about gpios 17, 18, and 24.  I thought that perhaps they were ones which were reassigned during the change from Rev.1 to Rev.2 boards.  If you don't use Broadcom numbers the numbering can go wrong if the board doesn't declare its revision in a standard way.  What command are you actually giving on the terminal?

Comment: Echo does text. Some driver variables need numbers not the text representation of a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post the exact command you are trying to use? Also, I assume you know for a fact that you are using a Rev.1 board, not a Rev.2.

For reference, to be sure, here is the page that describes the pin mapping from GPIO numbers to wiringPi numbers. http://wiringpi.com/pins/

Another way to test this is to export the pin and write straight to it from the command line. Try it. I actually found this pretty fascinating.

```
cd /sys/class/gpio
```

you should see an 'export' file and an 'unexport' file in there.

```
echo "18" > export
```

As you write to that file, you now have a symlink to a new device in that directory, called 'gpio18'. It's a directory so...

```
cd gpio18
```

You can now see a number of files. The ones we care about are "direction" and "value".

if you type

```
cat direction
```

it will print: 'in' or 'out' (I'm sure there are other values but I haven't played with them)

```
sudo echo "out" > direction
```

now, a "cat direction" should return 'out'.

```
cat value
```

will return 0 if the pin is low or 1 if the pin is high.

```
sudo echo "1" > value
```

sets the pin to high.

To verify, check "cat value" again.

That should be on.

Comment: Is it just me, or is that really cool? :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI

You may face issue like:

> echo: write error: Operation not permitted

when you're using command: `sudo echo "1" > value` if direction (cat direction) is set as 'out'. So first, change the direction as 'out' using command: `sudo echo "out" > direction` and then try to set 'value' as 1 or 0 to intended gpio pin using command like : `sudo echo "1" > value`